Improve performance of slow listview horizontal scroll
I wrote an app to collect book data and put it into a listview in .NET 8 using C# and Winforms (screenshot below). My listview has around 19 columns at the start, but will expand to about 50 - 70 when working with the data. Some of the columns are colored.

I do experience now poor performance of the listview control when more data will be placed (like about 100 list entries). The issue results in flickering when doing the horizontal and vertical scroll.
I could solve the vertical scroll flicker by using the following code for double buffering the listview control:
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SetDoubleBuffered(this System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView, bool doubleBuffered = true)
    {
        listView.GetType()
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)!
            .SetValue(listView, doubleBuffered, null);
    }
}

But what remains is the horizontal flickering. Additionally moving the horizontal slider with the mouse is slow as well and doesn´t behave fluent. It's not visible with 1-5 list entries but it starts with about 10-15 and gets worse the more entries I put into the list. I read that the Winforms listview redraws its entire contents even on small changes.
Is it possible to reduce the redraws of the listview control or get access to the horizontal slider?

Never tried but i don't think setting DoubleBuffered after creation of the control (after the handle of the control was created) has any effect. Derive from ListView set it in the constructor and then use that LIstView instead and see if it improves the behavior.

You didn't say or show but is custom drawing involved?

actually the code snippet solves the issue of the vertical scroll flickering. i just put it here for interest. But yes it doesnt solve the horizontal flcikering

no custom drawing is not involved. Im doing sum calculations for some of the entries but these are not done while scrolling

Have you thought about using a DataGridView instead of a ListView? Still double-buffering it (either with Reflection or building a Custom Control, then SetStyle() comes into play)
